# How can I make a floating block element occupy an entire page in Microsoft Word?

Tags: image-processing, layout, microsoft-word-365, typography

[image: word example]

I'm trying to have a picture occupy an entire page in Microsoft Word while the text flows around it, i.e. the paragraph would continue from the page before the picture directly to the page after the picture. In other words, I'm looking for the equivalent of LaTeX' `{figure}[p]`.

However, Word seems to insist that there is at least some text on the page with the floating element, as illustrated with the text box above (Wrap text setting is "top and bottom" here).

What is the solution to this?

Comment: I seriously need to have an answer to this, too. Maybe a bounty can be set...

Comment: @Cyberherbalist which version of Word ?

Comment: The current version -- Microsoft 365.

Comment: You may enlarge the image so it takes up a whole page. Questions: Where is the image found inside the text? Meaning is it in the middle of some paragraph, between paragraphs, after an empty line? Which text do you want to flow around it - that of the current paragraph? Note that a picture is always anchored to a paragraph and cannot be moved away from this one paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

This is a **Workaround**:

- be sure your image is inserted at the very beginning of the page, that is: your cursor position should be at the top of the page before inserting the image.
- right-click your image/element, and select `Wrap Text -> In line with text`.
- Then resize your picture such as to take the whole space of your page.

Note that the element won't be "floating", but it will be moving with the text: if you insert any text before the element, you'll need to reposition it at the beginning of the page.

Nonetheless for most cases this should be simple enough to use.

### EDIT:

(this is outside the scope of the original question, but was asked in a comment while a bounty was on)

If your image is not full page size, press twice `Ctrl+Enter` to insert two page breaks and thus get a blank page. Then, place your image as `wrap text -> in front of text` so you can put it anywhere on the page you want.
If your text needs to be justified at the end of the page preceding the image, first hit `Shift+Enter` at the end of the line to insert a manual line break within the paragraph, then press `Ctrl+Enter`to create the new page.

It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, and that's a decent workaround. I've kind of figured that out already, but if your page is portrait and your image is landscape, and making the image orientation portrait to match isn't a good fit, but you still want it to take up the whole page, this won't work very well. Another work around might be to insert a table, put the image in the table, and then make the table take up the whole page. I'll accept your answer if nobody comes in with a more "organic" way to do it. Or however that bounty thing works...

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Instead of inserting a table, just press twice `Ctrl+Enter` to insert two page breaks and get a blank page, then place your image as `wrap text -> in front of text` so you can put it anywhere on the page you want.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist See my edit

Comment: @Cyberherbalist alternatively without a table, you could isolate the picture to a section page, then set its vertical alignment to center. this still doesn't make the paragraph 'dynamic', however